# Why can't I set another workbook? (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

The macro is simple, but I have literaly NO IDEA what is going wrong! I've search everywhere for an answer but apparently no one else have had this same problem.

Here it is:

```
Sub Test()

Dim wkbkP As Workbook
Dim wkbk As Workbook

Set wkbkP = ThisWorkbook 'Principal workbook
Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\wb\Desktop\source.xlsx")

MsgBox (wkbkP.Name)
MsgBox (wkbk.Name)

End Sub
```

The ideia of the original macro is to use this `wkbk` as source for some data that I will use in the `wkbkP`.
Anyway, I was testing to see if it was working, but apparently it's not "reading" or "understanding" this line

```
Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\wb\Desktop\source.xlsx")
```

cause when I ask it to show `wkbk`'s name in the MsgBox, it shows me the same name as the `ThisWorkbook`(and no, they are not the same file).

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You should completely nullify the problem by getting rid of `ThisWorkbook` and just use the workbook's full name (i.e. `Workbooks("Workbook1")`).

Comment: What's the name of `ThisWorkbook` file?

Comment: There is never, ever, *ever* a need to copy the `ThisWorkbook` reference to another variable. Use the `ThisWorkbook` identifier to refer to the workbook that embeds your VBA project, wherever you need to refer to that particular workbook. Using `ThisWorkbook` consistently will make the code much easier to read, maintain, and debug, than if the `ThisWorkbook` reference is `wkbkP` somewhere, then `wb` somewhere else, and `ThisWorkbook` in another place.

Comment: Just to be sure: does source.xlsx opens when running macro? I woul also check FullName or Path to see what will in msgbox appear

Comment: Try `FullName`. Are they still the same? BTW that should be `MsgBox wkbk,Name`, not `MsgBox (wkbk.Name)` - these extraneous parentheses will inevitably cause headaches at one point or another, best lose the habit. What they are doing, is force-evaluate the `wkbk.Name` expression (returns a string), and then pass that value `ByVal` to the invoked procedure (here the `MsgBox` function). Notice the whitespace between `MsgBox` and the `(` - when parentheses *are* needed (e.g. when capturing the return value of a function), the VBE removes that space.

Comment: Thank y'all (really!) but It's still not working... I've tried all yout suggestions but it keeps "not reading" the `wkbk`.

Comment: FWIW there is nothing wrong with your code, so your question is hard to answer without knowing what values you're expecting. Excel will not open two workbooks that have the same name - would you happen to have `On Error Resume Next` in your real/actual code? If so, remove it. And please [edit] your post to include enough data (expected vs actual) and a [mcve] that we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Three questions and all you wrote is "not working". So how can we help you?

Comment: Open that file regularly (not via VBA), then in the Immediate Window (press CTRL+G in the VBEditor), type `?ThisWorkbook.Name`. Does the expected name get returned?